# boolean and index-slicing in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume I have a dataframe `df` and a column index `idx` - I can then get a new data frame only with the columns from `idx` and values which are equal to 1 by

`df_1=df[df==1].iloc[idx]`

but I think I have read somewhere, that slicing in that way is inefficient, since the first `df[df==1]` produces a new dataframe, which then is sliced.

Is it really not possible to do it in one line, such as
`df_1=df[df==1,idx]` or `df_1=df.iloc[df==1,idx]`

**EDIT: Added datasample**

(I know it looks like a np.array, but it is a pd.DataFrame)

`df=[[1,1,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,1]]`
expected return

`df_1=[[1,1,0],
        [0,0,1]]`

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: That has been added now

Comment: what is `idx` ?

Comment: it is written above - the column index I want to slice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First possible solution is test all rows for `1` and then filter columns by `idx`:

```
df= pd.DataFrame([[1,1,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0,1]], columns=list('abcde'))

idx = [0,1,4]
df_1 = df.iloc[(df==1).any(axis=1).values, idx]
print (df_1)
   a  b  e
0  1  1  0
2  0  0  1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df==1)
       a      b      c      d      e
0   True   True  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False   True
```

Or first filter columns by `idx` and then test for `1`:

```
df_1 = df.iloc[(df.iloc[:, idx]==1).any(axis=1).values, idx]
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.iloc[:, idx]==1)
       a      b      e
0   True   True  False
1  False  False  False
2  False  False   True
```